# BizTalk SMTP Message Part Getting XML Encoding

Tags: smtp, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have a email multi-part message which I am using to send failed message routing from the messagebox to a business users mailbox.

```
Email{ Body - RawString; OriginalMessage - string};
```

The original message gets set from the received message that activates the orchestration. For example assume the original failed message is from a Flat file that failed disassembly with the contents:

```
Order,1,2,3,4,5,<6>,
```

I set the message using:

```
Email.OriginalMessage = MyUtil.XlangMsgToStringMethod(FailedMessage);// XmlDocument type, this can be malformed xml, valid xml, or flat file that fails in disassembler.
```

I can then write to the event log to test whats in Email.OriginalMessage:

System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("BizTalk Server 2006", Email.OriginalMessage, Information); // This displays the correct original message "Order, 1,2,3,4,5,<6>,"

**When the email is delivered using a SMTP server and a dynamic send port, with the attachment set to text/plain mime type, the original message gets xml encoding escaped and wrapped in xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<string>Order, 1,2,3,4,5,&lt;6&gt;,</string>
```

**Any ideas why? The SMTP port has passthrutransmit as pipeline.**

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some more description about what you want the email message (including body) to look like after BizTalk sends it?

You mention that the Body part of the multipart message is set to RawString, but don't show any other code around this.  Are you sending text in the body of the email and if so is it being formatted correctly?  Are you trying to send an empty message with the contents contained in the attachment only?  Do you set any other properties on Email beside OriginalMessage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP port is getting XMLTransmit forcing the message to be treated as XML.
Switch to PassThroughTransmit.